# How add a thumbnail to a video in github's README file and that shows the thumbnail on mobile

Tags: github, video, html5-video, thumbnails, readme

I drag videos to the readme file and it's great because the user can play the video without leaving the repo's page. However on mobile it does not show a thumbnail of the video, see snapshot attached for this repo (safari ios 15.5 iphone 12). How can I add a thumbnail that shows when the [repo](https://github.com/sergiosolorzano/Unity-Dicom-3DRender) is viewed on mobile and it does not take the user to another page when plays the video?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: You have `controls="controls" muted="muted"` try also adding `playsinline` (or maybe wording it as `playsinline="playsinline"`)...

Comment: doesn't work, I get the same result, I tried for example <video src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24430655/176893082-cbd84e36-e1a6-43e7-a66e-0c1ad1fb441e.mp4" controls="controls" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline"></video> and <video src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24430655/176893082-cbd84e36-e1a6-43e7-a66e-0c1ad1fb441e.mp4" controls playsinline></video> as described here https://css-tricks.com/what-does-playsinline-mean-in-web-video/

Comment: I tested on a Nokia Android phone and the first video `rgba-range_picker` works okay to play inside the web page. It shows a picture (before play is pressed), but the other videos are showing blank white screens in the video plyers and don't play (they have durations but they auto-stop after 2 or 3 seconds without showing a picture). Are they saved differently?

Comment: Odd, all the same. On iOS iphone none render: README.md edited: + QuadMesh_CPU-RGBA_Range_Picker.unity: 

      <video src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24430655/176893082-cbd84e36-e1a6-43e7-a66e-0c1ad1fb441e.mp4" controls="controls" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline"></video>
      
    + QuadMesh_GPU_CB_Windowing.unity: 
  
      <video src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24430655/176882412-39a4156d-2e70-451a-b6c3-ac033135e69a.mp4" controls="controls" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline"></video>